# C# - how to select * from mysql to dataGridView1

Tags: c#, mysql, exception, datagridview

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0PtzO.png
this is my code. but I tried more other similar method, and always I have some Exception :( can you help me show data in datagridview?

connection is working (insert, update, delete is working ), but I can't do select to datagridview:/

sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Below code might help

```
 if (!this.IsPostBack)
    {
            string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
            using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(constr))
            {
                using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Customers"))
                {
                    using (MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter())
                    {
                        cmd.Connection = con;
                        sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                        using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                        {
                            sda.Fill(dt);
                            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                            GridView1.DataBind();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
    }
```

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Connect-Bind-GridView-to-MySql-database-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx